# Meaning of "skim" here

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context, vocabulary

I was watching the movie "Kajillionaire" and heard this quote:

> Once your face is in the system, they got you. Fines, 401k, home equity. But maybe you want all of that, I don't know. Me? I just prefer to skim.

So what does "to skim" mean in this context? I looked it up in the dictionary and saw some entries that I felt it might be related but I couldn't be sure.

> a. To embezzle (money) by taking a small portion on each transaction: corrupt governments skimming money from foreign aid.
> b. To fail to declare part of (certain income, such as winnings) to avoid tax payment.
> c. To copy information from (a credit card) as part of a skimming fraud.

So is he saying that he just prefers to skim (like embezzle from) the system?

Comment: "I just prefer to _pass unnoticed_". But I am only guessing.

Comment: Without more context, the meanings you found seem to be correct. Usually "skim" means to remove a thin top layer of something; in this case it refers to taking a little money off the top. It's a fairly common usage.

Comment: Dip one's toe in (harder for the sharks to identify than one's face?): almost certainly skim the surface, as fev says, not skim off the surface.

Comment: It could carry either or both senses. 1) *Glide **over** the surface* of conventional economic life (similar imagery to *living **under** the radar / **off-grid***, unnoticed by "the system"), AND/OR 2) Only take (without authority) small amounts "off the top", so as not to be noticed. Essentially, a POB "interpretation" issue.

Comment: See: [Kajillionaire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kajillionaire) "The entire family (who are scammers)  pride themselves on being skimmers and living on the bare minimum income"

Comment: @Cascabel so skimming is like living on the bare minimum income? Like the meaning FumbleFingers shared above. (2) Only take (without authority) small amounts "off the top", so as not to be noticed.)

Comment: Even after reading the Wiki entry, I have to admit that "skim"  in this sense seems to be a newer usage...it could be that they redefined it for the movie. What I am getting is that they live off-the-grid while committing small crimes to support their very basic life style.

Comment: Ok, thank you everyone for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sense as defined by the *[American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/SKIM)* would seem to be the intended one:

> [4]b. To glide or pass quickly and lightly over or along (a surface).

The speaker’s metaphor here likens him to a seabird that *skims* (flies just above) the water’s surface, merely dipping in its bill now and then to grab a little something of value—a tasty fish—as opposed to diving right in after prey, at the risk of becoming so wetted as to be unable to take to the air again right away. The speaker is boasting that he likewise employs speed and agility to avoid entanglement with the criminal justice system even while committing crimes.

I have not seen the movie in question so this is subject to correction by those who have.

Comment: I tend to agree with your logic.

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation!